# Bash script getting error in files

Tags: bash

Hi Guys pls help on this...

```
[root@uenbe1 ~]# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
cd /vol/cdr/MCA
no='106'
value='55'
size=`df -kh | grep '/vol/cdr/MCA' | awk '{print $5}'| sed 's/%//g'`
if [ "$size" -gt "$value" ] ;
then
delete=$(($size-$value))
echo $delete
count=$(($no*$delete))
`ls -lrth | head -n  $count   | xargs rm -rf`
fi
```

output:

```
+ cd /vol/cdr/MCA
+ no=106
+ value=55
++ df -kh
++ grep /vol/cdr/MCA
++ awk '{print $5}'
++ sed s/%//g
+ size=63
+ '[' 63 -gt 55 ']'
+ delete=8
+ echo 8
8
+ count=848
++ ls -lrth
++ head -n 848
++ xargs rm -rf
rm: invalid option -- 'w'
Try `rm --help' for more information.``
```

i want to delete these files which in $count.

Comment: If you go to the directory and do `ls -lrth | head -n 848`, what do you get then? Do you get a valid list of files? There's no *file* named `-w`?

Comment: yes am getting valid list. there is no file named with w

Comment: am not able to delete the value of count.

Comment: Are there any files with names that start with "-", or contain spaces or other unusual characters? BTW, you really should have an error check on the `cd` command (e.g. `cd cd /vol/cdr/MCA || { echo "Error cd'ing to MCA" >&2; exit 1; }`) -- otherwise if it fails, the script will be deleting files in some *other* directory...

Comment: This is the ls output: 
[root@uenbe1 MCA]# ls -lrth | head
total 29G
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M May 21 11:48 uenbe1_1463811505382_5715272012959687109.cdr
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M May 21 11:49 uenbe1_1463811535549_9088964979948456061.cdr
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M May 21 11:49 uenbe1_1463811565349_8232105259091872441.cdr
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M May 21 11:50 uenbe1_1463811595836_778926381450928326.cdr
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M May 21 11:50

Comment: That is the problem. You are passing the whole like from `ls -lrth` to `xarg`, which then passes it to `rm`. In other words, what `rm` sees is something like `rm -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M May 21 11:48 uenbe1_1463811505382_5715272012959687109.cdr -rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M May 21 11:49`. The solution is to `ls -rt` instead of `ls -lrth`.

Answer (score 1):

The command `ls -lrth` prints lines like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 bize bize    0 may 22 19:54 text.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 bize bize    0 may 22 19:54 manual.pdf
```

that text given to the command `rm` will be interpreted as options

```
$ rm -rw-r text.txt
rm: invalid option -- 'w'
```

---

List only the name of files. That is: remove the long `-l` option from ls (and the `-h` option since it works only with `-l`):

```
$ ls -1rt | head -n "$count" | xargs
```

But Please: do not make a `rm -rf` automatic, that is a sure path to future problems.

Maybe?:

```
$ ls -1rt | head -n "$count" | xargs -I{} echo rm -rf /vol/cdr/MCA/'{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you passing

```
ls -l
```

use just, it will find the list of file greater than given size, 
if you get this list in a file you can then take list of files which are to be deleted or whatever

```
find /vol/cdr/MCA -type f -size +56320c -exec ls '{}' \;
```

Comment: in this directory each file has same size i.e 9.6 MB. i want to do that it will delete the oldest files when it cross 75%

Comment: I guess you want to clean up old files based on dates, often get this question, check my blog if it helps you http://san-linux.blogspot.in/2010/06/find-files-betweend-dates.html

Answer (score 0):

```
>  `ls -lrth | head -n  $count   | xargs rm -rf`
```

This line has multiple problems. The backticks are superfluous, and you are passing the directory permission, file size, owner information etc as if that were part of the actual file name.

The minimal fix is to lose the backticks and the `-l` option to `ls` (and incidentally, the `-r` option to `rm` looks misplaced, too); but really, a proper solution would not use `ls` here at all.